# Orfeo Toolbox is not activating

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox

I am in desperate need of help. I've tried the answers to similar questions and nothing is working. Orfeo Toolbox appears as activated in Processing options but is not appearing in the toolbox. I checked to make sure the path was correct in the Options. Does anyone know how I can get it to show up in my toolbox?

Comment: Maybe it would be a good option to install everything with OSGEO4W: https://www.osgeo.org/projects/osgeo4w/

Comment: there is not otb in OSGeo4W and I don't see a future of adding otb into this